# Could not find prepared statement with handle 0. (SQL error)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to parse an XML into a table in XML with following statements:

```
INSERT INTO NewDeploymentComponentDetails([Value],[ComponentTypeId])
SELECT [Value],[ComponentTypeId]
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Deployment/Components/Component/ComponentDetails')
WITH
(
        Value NVARCHAR(255) 'Value',
    ComponentTypeId INT '../ComponentTypeId'
)
```

But getting error:

> Could not find prepared statement with handle 0. The statement has
>   been terminated.

Any idea about this error wrt statement above?

Comment: Hi Siya, I just saw, that you were "here" some minutes ago. Do you need further help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you have to know:

1) `FROM OPENXML` must be initialized by calling the system stored procedure `sp_xml_preparedocument`. As a result you get back the handle (your `@hDoc`) (set to value not equal to zero) as an ID to your prepared XML-data.

After your call you should deallocate the document calling `sp_xml_removedocument`.

Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx

2) `FOR OPENXML` is absolutely outdated and should not be used any more. There are really rare situations where it might help for better performance, but you should really switch over to the modern XPath/XQuery methods.

If you need help please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the solution , it helped out.